# RegisterHotkey and loop. break if the certain key pressed

Tags: c#, api

i have a hotkey and if i press that hotkey it will press f1 every 2 seconds and i want it to break the loop if f2 is pressed. can you guys help?

this code doesn't break the loop plz help

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int id = 0;     // The id of the hotkey. 
        RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, id, (int)KeyModifier.None, Keys.A.GetHashCode());
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        if (m.Msg == 0x0312)
        {


            Keys key = (Keys)(((int)m.LParam >> 16) & 0xFFFF);                  
            KeyModifier modifier = (KeyModifier)((int)m.LParam & 0xFFFF);       
            int id = m.WParam.ToInt32();                                        


            int i = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                SendKeys.Send("{F1}");

                if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.F2)
                {
                    break;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(i++);
            }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working on WinForms, you can easily do it with `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

First, place two `Timer`s in your form. (It will automatically goes component area)

One for key checking, one for key pressing

Set `Timer.Interval` whatever you want (called every N *ms*)
for example, if you set `Timer.Interval` to `100`, `Timer.Tick` event will fired every 100ms when Timer is enabled.

Double-click your timer component -> this will create Tick event for you

```cs
// timer1 for key checking, recommend you to set interval 10
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // check key press with GetAsyncKeyState
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.F1) == -32768) {
        // disable timer2 
        timer2.Enabled = false;
    }
}

// timer2 for key pressing, recommend you to set interval 2000
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    SendKeys.Send("{F1}");
}
```

GetAsyncKeyState on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) / [PInvoke](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getasynckeystate)

if you're Korean, you can refer [this blog](https://slaner.tistory.com/41) too.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of operation requires unmanaged Windows API's to properly execvute. Both the keyhook and the Keysend are a tricky beasts in themself. I can not help you with that part.

Regardless of that, you require some form of multitasking to pull this off. Your specific case should be solveable with a Timer. Propably even the minimalistic WindwosForms one. 2 seconds delay with a single sendkey is not anywhere close where it's limits become reelvant.

However if you want to learn proper Multitasking, you should consdier using the BackgroudnWorker instead. It is a very good way to learn Multitasking via Multithreading. If you go the route of Multithreading, this is code for rate limiting I once wrote up. Do mind that it must be run in an alternate Thread or adapted for Multitasking without Threads:

```
integer interval = 20;
DateTime dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddMillisconds(interval);

while(true){
  if(DateTime.Now >= dueTime){
    //insert code here

    //Update next dueTime
    dueTime = DateTime.Now.AddMillisconds(interval);
  }
  else{
    //Just yield to not tax out the CPU
    Thread.Sleep(1);
  }
}
```